Multiple error handling in bash script to restart container
I have below script, which is handling the error "TLS handshake failed" and restarting a app container if an error is found.
Now i want to add 2 more errors (no.2 and 3 below list) which I intend to update to restart a container "APP" if I see 3 errors in the EH logs. Please help with correct script.
3 errors are :

TLS handshake failed
Connection reset by peer
Failed to release a message

#!/bin/bash

# Set the container name
container_name="APP"

# Set the search string
search_string=("TLS handshake failed")

# Set the service name
service_name="dumpingserver"

# Check if the log contains the search string
if docker logs  --since 15m \$container_name 2>&1 | grep -q "\$search_string"; then
    echo "Search string found in \$container_name logs"

    # Restart the iotedge service
    if systemctl is-active --quiet \$service_name; then
        echo "Restarting the \$service_name service"
        systemctl restart \$service_name
    else
        echo "\$service_name service is not running, attempting to start it"
        systemctl start \$service_name
    fi
else
    echo "Search string not found in \$container_name logs"
fi


Why are you escaping the $ (i.e \$container_name) ?

Try grep with multiple templates: grep -E ''TLS handshake failed|Connection reset by peer|Failed to release a message"

@Ivan, starting that with '' and ending it with " isn't going to work so well.

The immediate and obvious problem is the extra backslashes preventing expansion. Whatever other problems you might have after fixing them should be asked about separately. (BTW, you might want to get in the habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and reading the wiki pages it links).

(BTW, tag sh or bash, not both at once -- and with a script starting with #!/bin/bash, the tag should only be bash)

(As a completely separate matter, don't do this at all: you can make a one-shot systemd service that's started in response to dumpingserver exiting to decide how to handle that exit, or configure systemd's built-in restart behavior to taste; moreover, if that server is something you wrote yourself, update the code to make the TLS handshake failure immediately fatal and systemd will immediately be in a position to restart after it triggers)
